# Mysql Procedure with days and hours for a complete year

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Im triying to create this mysql procedure to make a table with all days and all hours of this year,(one hour interval.)

```
CREATE TABLE FECHAS
(
  created_at datetime
);

CREATE PROCEDURE filldates(dateStart DATE, dateEnd DATE)
BEGIN

      WHILE dateStart <= dateEnd DO
        INSERT INTO FECHAS (created_at) VALUES (dateStart);
        SET dateStart = date_add(dateStart, INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
      END WHILE;
    END;//

CALL filldates('2015-01-01 00:00:00','2015-12-31 23:00:00');
```

But only i get this:

```
2015-01-01 00:00:00
2015-01-01 00:00:00
2015-01-01 00:00:00
2015-01-01 00:00:00
2015-01-01 00:00:00
```

I want to do this:

```
2015-01-01 00:00:00
2015-01-01 01:00:00
2015-01-01 02:00:00
2015-01-01 03:00:00
2015-01-01 04:00:00
2015-01-01 05:00:00
.....
2015-12-31 23:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your parameter datatypes from `DATE` to `DATETIME`. There are no hours in `DATE`, so when you add 1 hour to the date, it doesn't change.